# drysrape install Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: javascript, python, ubuntu, web-scraping, dryscrape

I'm having trouble implementing dryscrape on and ubuntu 16.04 server (clean install on digital ocean) - with the objective of scraping JS populated websites.

I'm following dryscrape install instructions from [here](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev build-essential \
                  python-lxml python-pip xvfb

pip install dryscrape
```

and then running the following python script which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python/26440563) as well as the test html page at the same link. (It returns html or JS)

**Python**

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = dryscrape.Session()
my_url = 'http://www.example.com/scrape.php'
session.visit(my_url)
response = session.body()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
soup.find(id="intro-text")
```

**HTML** - scrape.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Javascript scraping test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id='intro-text'>No javascript support</p>
  <script>
     document.getElementById('intro-text').innerHTML = 'Yay! Supports javascript';
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

When I do I can't seem to get the expected return data, instead it's just errors.

I'm wondering if there is anything obvious that I'm missing ?

Note: I've trawled numerous install guides/threads and can't seem to get it working. I've also attempted to use selenium but can't seem to get anywhere with it either. Many thanks.

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "js.py", line 3, in <module>
    session = dryscrape.Session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dryscrape/session.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.driver = driver or DefaultDriver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dryscrape/driver/webkit.py", line 30, in __init__
    super(Driver, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 230, in __init__
    self.conn = connection or ServerConnection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 507, in __init__
    self._sock = (server or get_default_server()).connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 450, in get_default_server
    _default_server = Server()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit_server.py", line 424, in __init__
    raise NoX11Error("Could not connect to X server. "
webkit_server.NoX11Error: Could not connect to X server. Try calling dryscrape.start_xvfb() before creating a session.
```

---

**Working Script**

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dryscrape.start_xvfb()
session = dryscrape.Session()
my_url = 'https://www.example.com/scrape.php'
session.visit(my_url)
response = session.body()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
print soup.find(id="intro-text").text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no X server running. The clue is

> Try calling dryscrape.start_xvfb() before creating a session

See http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

```
if 'linux' in sys.platform:
    # start xvfb in case no X is running. Make sure xvfb 
    # is installed, otherwise this won't work!
    dryscrape.start_xvfb()
```

http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

> xvfb_ (necessary only if no other X server is available)

So you can just add:

```
dryscrape.start_xvfb()
```

before:

```
session = dryscrape.Session()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added in an updated/working python script to the bottom of my answer. Only additional thing I needed to add was to specify the html parser within `soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")` really appreciate the help as I spent 4 hours reading and trying to solve yesterday.